# Access child form name from base form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows application which has one base form. All other forms are inherited from this base form.

I want to log the start and end time of every child form. However, I do not want to log the time from every child form.

Is it possible to access the child form name from base form somehow?

Comment: It is just `this.Name`, *after* the child's constructor completes.  So use OnHandleCreated() or OnLoad().  Pretty unclear why the name matters to suppress logging, just use a LoggingSuppressed property in the base class.